# Can VM / Machine IP be used instead of Proxy Server for Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a Scrapy crawler and I want to rotate the IP so my application will not be blocked. I am setting IP in scrapy using `request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://51.161.82.60:80'` but this is a VM's IP. My question is can VM or Machine's IP be used for scrapy or I need a proxy server?

Currently I am doing this. This does not throw any error but when I get response from `http://checkip.dyndns.org` it is my own IP not updated IP which I set in meta. That is why I want to know if I do need proxy server.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting your own IP is because your VM is 'transparent'. You will need to intercept your request at the VM, remove tracking headers such as X-Forwarded-For, and your server has to know who to respond to when it receives the response from the website you are crawling.

The simplest solution though, is to install a proxy service on your VM, for example [Squid](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/squid.html.en), then set `forwarded_for off` to make it an anonymous proxy server. There may be other request options to tweak to make it truly anonymous. Remember to secure the whitelisted IP addresses with `http_access allow specialIP` and `acl specialIP src x.x.x.x` in `/etc/squid/squid.conf`. The default port of Squid is 3128.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you need a proxy server. meta data is only a field in the http request. the server side still knows the public ip that really connecting from the tcp connection layer.